# ng-show if subarray has any elements after filter is applied

Tags: angularjs

I have groups of widgets.  The widgets only display on some condition.  If a group has no widgets to display, I'd like to hide the group (accordion) all together.

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="widgetGroup in widgetGroups" ng-show="**Any widgets below exist after filtering**">
    <input type="radio" ng-repeat="widget in widgetGroup.Widgets | filter: showThisWidget">
</accordion-group>
```

Comment: What do `widgetGroups` and `showThisWidget()` look like?

Comment: `showThisWidget` is a boolean maybe.  WidgetGroups has `Label: string` and `Widgets: Widget[]`.

Comment: I was asking to see this code to help debug or propose alternatives for what you're trying to do. Please share the relevant controller/directives